# Scroll with pictures

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I'm programming on objective-c. How can I create scroll with paging enabled like this.

[image]

Comment: let my google that for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665496/uiscollview-with-paging-enabled-like-a-simple-image-gallery

Answer (score -1):

First check the property of scroll view for Paging enabled.Then set your scroll view content size corresponding to how much page you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this implementation 
https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView

There's also a nice website for custom cocoa controls http://cocoacontrols.com/, where you can find very good stuff, so you won't need to invent the wheel =)